# Using named variables in combination with prefixMatch and pathPrefixRewrite

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I want to setup a URL map that points to a single backend service `api-backend` for these routes:

```
GET    https://api.domain.com/:version/products
POST   https://api.domain.com/:version/products
GET    https://api.domain.com/:version/products/:id
POST   https://api.domain.com/:version/products/:id
DELETE https://api.domain.com/:version/products/:id
```

The path to these routes on backend service needs to be prefixed with `/api`. I'd like to use named variables to pass the api version [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#pm-constraint).

The issue I'm running into, is that I need to define 2 route rules for all routes to work:

- one for the endpoints without `:id` parameter
- one for the endpoints with `:id` parameter

The following URL map works but has 2 route rules to support all endpoints:

```yaml
defaultService: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
name: api-matcher
routeRules:
- description: Product
  matchRules:
  - pathTemplateMatch: /{version=*}/products/{params=**}
  priority: 0
  service: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathTemplateRewrite: /api/{version}/products/{params}
- description: Products
  matchRules:
  - pathTemplateMatch: /{version=*}/products
  priority: 1
  service: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathTemplateRewrite: /api/{version}/products
```

I'd like to combine these in 1 route rule, but it seems that additional URL parameters are not passed unless I create 2 route rules and explitely pass `{params}` for the endpoints containing `:id`.

I've tried working with `prefixMatch` instead of `pathTemplateMatch` and `pathPrefixRewrite` instead of `pathTemplateRewrite`. That works fine if I do not use a named variable for `:version`, but instead pin it to a fixed version (e.g. `v1`):

```yaml
defaultService: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
name: api-matcher
routeRules:
- description: Products
  matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /v1/products
  priority: 0
  service: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /api/v1/products
```

However, when I replace `v1` with a named variable `version`, the endpoints are not working anymore:

```yaml
defaultService: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
name: api-matcher
routeRules:
- description: Products
  matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /{version=*}/products
  priority: 0
  service: projects/my-project/global/backendServices/api-backend
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /api/{version}/products
```

I'm looking for advice on how to use `prefixMatch` and `pathPrefixRewrite` in combination with named variables, but the documentation does not describe if that's possible - and I'm not sure what the difference is with `pathTemplateMatch`. Any suggestions are welcome.

Alternatively, I'd be happy to achieve the same with `pathTemplateMatch` and `pathTemplateRewrite`, as long as I don't have to create multiple route rules for each version, or for each endpoint.